# How to run maven generated executable jar file on another system?

Tags: windows, maven

I created a pom.xml to compile java files. and it works fine. Inside target folder an executable jar is generated as i ran mvn install command. Now how can I deploy/run this jar file on another system?Basically I need to deploy my build on another system. How is that possible?

Please  help.

Gouthami

Comment: What a System? linux? tomcat? jboss?

Comment: Do you want to publish it using Maven?

Comment: @gouthami your last 5 questions are stil unsolved! Please **accept answers!**

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jar to the other system and use `java -jar filename.jar`

Comment: IF I use java -jar filename.jar then it says "no main manifest attribute" . I do not have ant class which has main method.

Comment: In your question you say you have an "Executable jar".  How is this true if you do not have a main class and a correct manifest.

Comment: Its a executable jar generated by maven automatically... So its basically not including main-class attribute in MANIFEST.MF  file

Comment: But do you have a main class in your jar?  Anyway, this response is not relevant since you want to deploy via maven.